# c# .net interop close dialog boxes

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop

After opening a Word document, using .NET interop, a dialog box is created that blocks programmatic editing of the opened file. The user cannot see the winword.exe process and so cannot close the dialog. Is there a way to close a dialog or to prevent them being opened on startup?

I believe it might be the dialog asking first time users to set their name and initials.

Note: I know that it would be nicer to avoid using the interops and am familiar with Aspose products.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I would try to find a way to do something similar to the Interaction.SendKeys VBA function.

Comment: ...and send an Escape key.  I'm almost certain that will close all modal Word dialogs.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Do Fooles comments work for you? We're havind similar problems with corrupted documents giving a warning dialog. When we programmatically try to close Word, there's a new dialog telling the user to close the first dialog.

Comment: I went in a different direction and so did not attempt Foole's way. I do think though that Foole's comment sound like a possible way to get around this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360481/disabling-overwrite-existing-file-prompt-in-microsoft-office-interop-filesaveas-m)

Basically, you need to disable all "alerts", such the dialog that you describe above.  Instead of "MSProject", use "Word" of course.