# How to disable popups when opening a file using Microsoft.Office.Interop

Tags: c#, ms-office, office-interop, office-pia

Such as read-only confirm, other alerts.
What to do with these popups? Or ignore them?

Answer (score 32):

See my answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360481/disabling-overwrite-existing-file-prompt-in-microsoft-office-interop-filesaveas-m)

Basically, you disable all alerts via the "Display Alerts" method:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.[OFFICE_APP].Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.[OFFICE_APP].Application();
app.DisplayAlerts = false;
```

where [OFFICE_APP] is the name of the Office program you're using, such as Word, Excel, etc.

Comment: I have set this, but there also a popups for read-only confirm box etc.

Comment: Is the read-only confirmation box your main concern? If so, have you tried opening the document with ReadOnly set to false and/or IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended set to true in the open() method?  See here for what I'm referring to:  [Workbooks.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open(v=office.11).aspx)

Comment: As of Interop 2013 You can not use true or false, instead use  Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlersNone / ...

Comment: @dotNetkow i have set the readonly proerty to true after that the code stop working :(

Comment: @user3217843 are you using 2013? see CantGetANick's response above. Different value to use.

Comment: @dotNetkow i am using word 2010.

Comment: You're great! I read dozens of non helpful answers, and had to waste a lot of precious time, before eventually finding your answer...

Comment: @CantGetANick I used your solution and used Document.OpenNoRepairDialog too, to open the document, but still prompt appears.

Comment: @AniketBhansali I have no other solution :) Good luck

Comment: Microsoft Word
The last time you opened 'Sample.docx', it caused a serious error. Do you still want to open it?
I get above message and my program stop working. Have you got anything similar.

Comment: @BruceDou Do make sure that you `enable` the `DisplayAlerts` back after your code so it's not disabled for other tasks where you may want usera to be warned before taking any actions where warning is necessary.

Answer (score 6):

Here is another alternative to prevent the Security message asking you to allow macros.

I read [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._application.automationsecurity(v=office.14).aspx) from MSDN and figured out the following code:

```
Application wordApp = new Application()
{
    Visible = false,
    AutomationSecurity = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
};
```

Since a copy of the file is made before opening it I don't have to change the AutomationSecurity back to the default setting.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a note: for some file formats (I tested .XLS, but probably others too) that are password protected, `app.DisplayAlerts = false` will NOT bypass the password dialog.

In this situation, you can simply pass a fake password on open, which will throw an error. Catch it if you want.

```
var app = new Application();
app.DisplayAlerts = false;
var workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(filePath, "fakePassword"); // Bypasses dialog, throws error
```

In this situation the error thrown is:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The password you supplied
>   is not correct. Verify that the CAPS LOCK key is off and be sure to
>   use the correct capitalization.

Answer (score 2):

Dear "**Uriel Fernandez**" with his thought
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.automationsecurity?view=excel-pia

directed me to another thought https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.screenupdating?view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel__Application_ScreenUpdating

So can try disabling it **_Application.ScreenUpdating** and ... "You won't be able to see what the code is doing, but it will run faster"

**EDIT**

```
Word.Application app = null;
try
{
app = new Word.Application();
app.Visible = false;
app.DisplayAlerts = Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
app.AutomationSecurity = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable;
app.ScreenUpdating = false;
// work ...
}
catch {}
app.Quit();
if (app != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
```

Comment: That's a great addition, thanks for sharing!

Comment: Will not work if machine is running excel 365

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application appWord = new 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

appWord.DisplayAlerts = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
```

This will disable the popups.

Comment: What does this answer add on top of the already posted other answer?

Comment: this does not work... I get popup error executing a macro

Answer (score 0):

For anyone cursed enough to still have to work with Excel Interop.

What MIGHT work is using the NetOffice.Excel nuget package and setting the following:

```
            xlApp.Visible = false;
            xlApp.ScreenUpdating = false;
            xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
            xlApp.AutomationSecurity = NetOffice.OfficeApi.Enums.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityLow;
            xlApp.AskToUpdateLinks = false;
            xlWorkbook.UpdateLinks = NetOffice.ExcelApi.Enums.XlUpdateLinks.xlUpdateLinksAlways;
```

If you're using excel 365 you'll still get privacy levels warnings, and remember that `DisplayAlerts = false;` doesn't disable security/privacy warnings.

To stop privacy level warnings on 365 you need to disable privacy firewall on power query:

1. Open your Excel workbook.
2. From the ribbon, select Data > Get Data > **Query Options**.
3. On the left-hand side, under Global, select **Privacy**
4. Select **Always Ignore Privacy level settings**.

Setting the `'AutomationSecurity`' to low via code was supposed to do this, but it wouldn't work for me.

For other warnings about external data, something you can try is disable it yourself on your server's excel configurations:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/enable-or-disable-security-alerts-about-links-and-files-from-suspicious-websites-a1ac6ae9-5c4a-4eb3-b3f8-143336039bbe