# How to open Excel-workbooks without the message The workbook contains links to other data sources. programmatically?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I want to open 1 or more Excel-workbooks programmatically. And when I open the workbook, you get a question: **The workbook contains links to other data sources.** And I don't want press "**Don't update**"

How can you leave this messagebox? So the functionality will not interrupted anymore. Updating is not needed.

[image]

Comment: You say you're opening the workbook programmatically. Are you using the Microsoft Office Interop libraries? If so, you should tag your question with that.

Comment: If this is using Microsoft Interop, potential duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575117/how-to-disable-popups-when-openning-in-office-interop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try placing in the workbook Open event handler:

```
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
```

Comment: This looks the best answer in my situation, because I do not use OleDbConnection.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get around the dialogs with the excel interop libraries (the warnings are there for a reason).  The way I've always done this in the past is to treat the Excel file like it's a database, and use the following:

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelFileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\"");
```

Then you can use the following to get information about the sheets:

```
DataTable lookupSheets = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
```

Then use the debugger to understand what is behind the lookupSheets variable and start writing queries like you would with any other database.

**Note**: You cannot use the richer elements of the interop libraries like formatting

Comment: This answer might not apply to your situation.  If it doesn't please let me know.